# Should I have edited the imperial measurement to an answer?

Tags: discussion, editing

I was reading [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/168592/is-it-possible-to-prolong-the-life-of-a-cartridge-battery) and came across this answer that

> Batteries are best stored at temperatures of 20°C

Now I went and edited the answer to be

> Batteries are best stored at temperatures of 20°C / 68°F

Since I just spent time doing the conversion, due to me not know what temperature 20°C really is. Now looking back at it I was confused if I should of gone ahead and done this. I would thinks yes as this is a minor edit and it is now much easier to understand for a wider audience.

I wondering what others think is the best policy is in this situation.

Comment: Meh, only like three weird countries use imperial for temperatures =p

Comment: I get the metric system I just can not relate in my head was 20°C is.  It goes like this.... Ok it's 1/5 of the temperature of boiling water. So I guess it's cold?

Comment: I think a better solution would be to remove the imperial system from the planet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see a problem with this at all. As long as the information is correct, and works with what is already there (in this case, matches the already present Celcius temperature), there's no reason why it would ever be a bad thing. :)

Just make sure that you are checking the whole post to make sure there aren't any other edits (spelling, grammar, etc) that you can do to make the post as awesome as possible each time you edit. :)

Answer (score 3):

Sure. If an edit improves the post significantly, which the addition of Fahrenheit obviously does as it offers the same information to more people, it's fine. Just make sure you improve the post as far as you can with that same one edit.